# How to iterage with Json looking for determinate index?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

To start, I have a JSON which contain arrays and dicts, this is a example of structure.

```
JSON {} 
 - nav []
   - 0 {title, view-list, ...}
    - subitems []
      - 0 {title, view-list, ...}
```

Thinking in that structured, inside array nav, I have dicts which contains datas as `title and view-list` two of exists importants content which need extract. but inside dicts there is anothers arrays with other dicts with theses importants values `title, view-list`.

```
JSON
navtree
     0
      id : 811566
      title : "Services"
      view-list : "2"
      subsections
        0
         id : 811568
         title : "inetd Services"
         view-list : "2.1"
```

navtree can has 10 positions, each position can has another 10 and so on. This would be a extensive nested for loop. How I would extract these values using a recursive way?

Json Data - https://pastebin.com/27JHunmn

Comment: Can you show some actual JSON data rather than pseudo-JSON

Comment: I updated the code with data link

Comment: This looks like a hybridization of YAML and JSON, interestingly enough.

Comment: Any idea what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) is what you would want.

Here is a complete example for your use case. Parsing the dictionary to one list of NavItem objects.

```
# Nav Item object - makes it easier to work with later on.
class NavItem():
    def __init__(self, title, view_level, **kwargs):
        self.title = title
        self.view_level = view_level

# parse nested Array of Dict Items to Array of NavItem
def parseNavItems(Items):
    parsedItems = []
    for Item in Items:
        for k in {'subsections_for_nav_tree', 'recommendations_for_nav_tree'}:
            if k in Item:
                parsedItems.extend(parseNavItems(Item[k]))
        parsedItems.append(NavItem(**Item))
    return parsedItems
```

You would call the function with `allItems = parseNavItems(j['navtree'])` - whatever your `j` is. You may extract the data with `allItems[0].title` by utilizing the NavItem class.

Comment: excelent, I got to use parseNavItems, but you could give me a example to use the class?

Comment: The class is used in the parseNavItems function. parsedItems.append(NavItem(**Item)) creates a new class object for each item.